# Is it possible to use Microsoft Visual Studio to build an UI for a CPLEX Optimization Model?

Tags: optimization, interface, cplex

I'm currently building a timetable model on CPLEX O.S. My question is: is it possible to connect it to Microsoft Visual Studio in order to create an UI to let the user enter the initial data and parameters? Or maybe let Excel be the data input interface and then have a V.S built interface to load that file and begin the optimization problem? I would like to make it as easier as possible to optimize a timetable using the model I'm creating. I've been searching for it and found something called Concert Technology, not sure if this is what I need, still learning about it.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, really helpful. I found some examples in the main folder of CPLEX O.S using V.S and OPL, they use the standard console to run the optimization process, and with that in mind, I would be able to use Windows Forms instead of that console, and using C++ or maybe C#, insert the initial data and then call the optimizer using the same idea as seen in the examples?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. If you're going to be using Visual Studio, the easiest option is probably to create a GUI application using .NET. Then, you can consume the CPLEX .NET API from within your application. Another option would be to use C++, but that would probably be considerably more complex. There's really no difference between calling CPLEX from a GUI application versus calling CPLEX from a console application. Usually you would add some logic to a button click event handler that would build the model in CPLEX, solve it, and gather the solution information. Take a look at the [CPLEX User's Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/usrmancplex.html), [CPLEX .NET Reference Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refdotnetcplex/html/R_Project.htm), [CPLEX C++ Reference Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/overview.html), and the many examples that are included with CPLEX when you install the software.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, as Alex and rkersh already said. It is much much simpler than people expect to just write your application as you want it to be in C# or C++ (or any of the other supported languages). Then just use the CPLEX Concert API calls into the CPLEX library to build and solve your model and retrieve the answers. It won't make any difference to the performance of your model whichever language you use. Using the CPLEX API means that it is just like any other library. CPLEX is just software like any other.

Answer (score -1):

there are many options:

- You can write everything in C++ or C# with the CPLEX Concert API https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/Cplusplus/cpp_synopsis.html
- You may call OPL from C++ or C# with API https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplinterfaces/topics/opl_interf_intro_cpp.html
- You may try VSTO : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplinterfaces/topics/opl_interfaces_work_integrateExcel.html
- You may call OPL from Excel